# cant import NYXImagesKit library

Tags: ios, xcode, import

I am trying to import the NYXImagesKit library in to my iOS 5.1 project but it will not show up as importable code. It cannot find the library. I have dragged the NYXImagesKit library in to the project and added the libraries. I have also added the following to my build phases:

[image]

[image]

However I still get an error saying it cannot find NYXImagesKit.h when i try to import it.

NYXImagesKit can be found from here: https://github.com/Nyx0uf/NYXImagesKit

Ive used this in a previous project so I know that it works.

screenshot of location of .h file:

[image]

header search paths:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not having an issue with "importing" the library proper. (I would not like to appear pedantic, but a library is linked, not imported). The issue you are having is with the header file which comes with the library.

To fix it, you should make sure to add the path to `NYXImagesKit.h` in your project build sentting (Search Headers Path). This can by found under Build options in your project settings.

Alternatively, an easier way is to add the `NYXImagesKit.h` file to your project (like any .m file). Then it will be found without the need to specify an header search path.

EDIT:

Since from what you report, everything seems ok, he only idea I can come up with is making sure that the paths are defined for your target (as opposed to the project overall); but I guess it is already like that.

Other than that, only resort is thinking that the project got corrupted somehow. You can inspect the project.pbxproj file inside your .xcodeproj document with a text editor and ensure that everything looks fine.

If everything fails, just start over with a new project.

Comment: I tried this and it is not working. That is, specifying to search in the directory that NYXImagesKit.h resides in both the Header Search Path and a User Header Search Path section: /Users/myuser/Documents/iOS/Libraries/NYXImageKit/Helper

Comment: what about adding the file to the project? Are you sure that the header file is in the helper directory and not in class? I cannot access github to have a look because it's down for maintenance...

Comment: i updated my question with the screenshot of the directory the .h file seems to be in.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/P8vCl.png

Comment: also add a screenshot of your header search path setting... (or write here its value).